# Retornar varios valores en un For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bucle-for, tweepy

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Twitter el cual debe ser accesado por medio de Tkinter, el caso es que primero habia diseñado una funcion solo en python, usaba un loop 'For' y con print veía lo que me este me daba como resultado. El caso es que como de un widget de Tkinter invoco a la funcion necesito que esta me retorne esos resultados para que puedan aparecer en la GUI. Se sabe que al aprecer el primer return el loop se termina, por lo tanto necesito saber una forma para que la funcion me retorne todos los valores que necesito sin problema. A continuacion pongo el codigo de la funcion y la parte de la Tkinter, ya que quiero meter esta información en un widget de Text. Muchas gracias, espero una respuesta pronta.

```
 def timeline():
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(2):
# Procesa el home timeline  
     return (status.user.name)
     return (status.user.screen_name)
     return (status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
```

Y necesito meter esa informacion en un text widget que luce así:

```
 tweets=Text(stream,bg='Sky Blue',fg='white')
 tweets.pack(padx=10,pady=10 )
 tweets.config(state='normal')
 tweets.insert(END,timeline())
 tweets.config(state='disabled')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, ten en cuenta que una función solo puede tener una único `return` ya que es la última clausula que se ejecutará en la función.

Ahora bien, lo que necesitas es retornar un valor compatible con lo que espera el método `insert()` y no es otra cosa que una cadena. Por lo que podríamos hacer que `timeline()` retorne dicho dato. Por ejemplo:

```
def timeline():
  cadena = ""
  for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(2):
    cadena = cadena + "{0} {1} {2}\n".format(status.user.name,status.user.screen_name,status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))

  return cadena
```

Básicamente recorremos la lista y formateamos una linea con los tres valores separados por un espacio y con un fin de linea al final.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, sirvió exactamente como lo necesitaba, solo ocupo hacer un salto de linea entre las distintas cosas que obtengo (username,screen name y text) no sé si será posible. Una consulta extra, ¿no sabes como obtener el texto completo de un tweet? he buscado y ninguna de las soluciones me funciona

Comment: Un salto de línea los puedes indicar con `\n`, por ejemplo para separa cada uno de los valores: `"{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(status.user.name,status.user.screen_name,status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))`

Comment: Ahora si quedó perfecto, muchas gracias